# How do I clear the values inserted on save command in MVVM WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, save

I am able to save the data to database using the save command.
But the entered data is not cleared after successfully save operation.

How do I clear the values in ViewModel itself.

Thanks

Comment: You really need to be more specific, it's hard to tell what exactly you're asking... What do you mean "clear the values" ? Why do you want to clear them anyway ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy - you instantiate ("new up") a new ViewModel and bind it to the View. What makes you think you need to recycle the old one?

Arguably a ViewModel should not know about clearing itself - that is the job of the Model, and the easiest most pain free way to do it is to new up another one, throw the old one away.

Comment: Yes make them throw away after use.